# Correct includes to use the new C++ API in opencv 2.3

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, include

I'm familiar with the old opencv 1, and used its C functions for a long time. However, I have problems with switching to the C++ API of opencv 2.3

I downloaded the latest stable version (2.3.1), but the examples in it use either the old C functions, or include `"opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"`.

The problem is, **the only file in my `include/opencv2` directory is `opencv.hpp`**. If I include that, there are a lot of paths which are incorrect.
Inside of `opencv.hpp` there are such things as:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/flann/miniflann.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
```

etc.

However, in my opencv directory, the include files are in folders like:

```
modules/core/include/opencv2/core
modules/flann/include/opencv2/flann
modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc
```

etc.

So, what is the point of that `opencv.hpp`, if I have to specify the include path manually for every single header? On the opencv site (http://opencv.willowgarage.com) the tutorials are either hopelessly outdated, or they don't address this question at all and jump straight to the algorithms.

**Edit:** I'm using Qt, if that matters. I downloaded the source from http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/branches/2.3/ and built it successfully.

**Edit2:** Yes, it mattered. One of the Qt headers was missing, and so the building process of opencv skipped a few libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem. The Qt source I have (4.6.3) does not have `qconfig.h` in `corelib/global`, so when I built `opencv`, not all libraries were created, and the headers were not copied.

Just so others with the same problem will know it and not waste hours finding for a solution: `qtconfig.h` is not included in the Qt source distribution. You have to create that file yourself, there are a number of templates in its directory, either rename one of them (`qconfig-large`, `qconfig-minimal`, etc.), or just create an empty `qconfig.h`.

Edit: I don't recommend this way to anyone. I downloaded created a mingw make, redownloaded everything, and it works now. I had to take care that the mingw version I built opencv is the same as the one used with Qt.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been using opencv 2.3.1 for too long, but so far using the includes from `opencv` has been enough

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
```

Comment: `cv.h` contains the following: `#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"`
`#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"`
`#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"`
`#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"` etc., so I still have the same problem. What include paths do you use? Did you manually set all include paths for opencv2/... ?

Comment: @vsz I guess the point of `opencv/cv.h` is htat you don't have to worry about the individual includes. If you want to be more fine-grained then you can include e.g. `opencv/cxcore.h` and so on.

Comment: The problem is, that when I include `opencv/cv.h` I get compiler errors because it cannot find `"opencv2/core/core_c.h"` and all the others.

Comment: Did you install opencv, or just build? everything I need ended up in /usr/local/include/opencv and /usr/local/include/opencv2.

Comment: First I installed the complete superpack, then I discovered that under Qt I cannot used the libraries, so I downloaded the whole source, and built it myself. Did I miss a step?

Comment: It could be. I am on linux, and cmake, make, make install. What platform are you on?

Comment: Windows, and I did use cmake to generate the makefiles.

Comment: @vsz sorry, I don't know anything about the windows build system or include paths.

Comment: I fear it has nothing to do with Windows. Here is the structure in the source depository: http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/branches/2.3/opencv/modules/ and as you can see, the headers are not in `include/opencv/HEADERNAME.h` but under `modules/HEADERNAME/include/opencv2/HEADERNAME/HEADERNAME.h`. How does your `include/opencv` and `include/opencv2` folders look like? In mine, I only have the old headers in `opencv` and `opencv.hpp` in `opencv2`, but they all include things like core/core.hpp etc. which are not there, but under `modules/....`

Comment: But when you build, the `modules` part gets lost and all headers should end up in `opencv` and `opencv2`. Did you follow [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide)?

Comment: Maybe not for Windows. I tried the Windows megapack which is a binary package, and the `opencv` and `opencv2` dirs were the same. Well, I can still try copying all the headers there manually, and see what happens.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you'd have to copy files by hand or that all the includes you need are in places other than 'opencv' and 'opencv2', so I think something must have gone wrong with your build.

Comment: Yes, the build did go wrong, at least partially. I'm sorry I wasted your time, it seems I was on the wrong track the whole time.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently started to learn opencv (2.3), and as juanchopanza mentions, that should suffice. I'm using osx and have opencv 1.0 installed as well, so a basic program on my machine looks like this:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    namedWindow("HelloCV2");
    imshow("image",imread("../HelloCV2/dolphin_1.jpg"));
    waitKey(5000);
    return 1;
}
```

Make sure your path's are correctly setup. 
Currently I'm using Qt, so the .pro file looks like this:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = HelloCV2
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /opt/local/include/ #this is where the header files are on my machine
LIBS += /opt/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.3.1.dylib
LIBS += /opt/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.3.1.dylib
```

HTH

Comment: BTW both those includes seem to be in `opencv/highgui.h`

Comment: You have `<YOUR_OPENCV_DIR>/include` in your include path, so your `#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>` will be actually `#include <YOUR_OPENCV_DIR>/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp>`. My problem is, that in my `include/opencv2` directory there is **nothing** besides `opencv.hpp`. All the other headers are in their separate directories, just as I wrote it in the question.

Comment: @vsz What os are you using ? if you search on your file system for the missing header files do they show up at all ?

Comment: @George Profenza: Yes, they show up. See the second part of my question: `modules/core/include/opencv2/core`, `modules/flann/include/opencv2/flann`, etc.

Comment: @George Profenza: Under Windows, it's like `C:\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2\core\core.hpp`.

Comment: You can see the sources here: http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/branches/2.3/opencv/modules/ This is where I downloaded them from, so the headers are **not** in `opencv/HEADERNAME.h` but under `modules/HEADERNAME/include/opencv2/HEADERNAME/HEADERNAME.h`

Answer (score -1):

The trick is to build the 'install' project. That will collect all the headers, etc, into one directory and will enable the include structure that the examples show.

```
# create a build-directory, run cmake etc.
make
make install
```

Comment: In-order it to be a good answer, please add some code or example, this type of answer should be actually a comment