# Does OpenCV need to be compiled before using?

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to install OpenCV on Windows. Following are how I installed it:

1. Download OpenCV 2.4.2.exe from sourceforge.
2. unarchived it.
3. open Eclipse CDT.
4. Add C:/opencv/include/opencv  to "Includes"
5. Add opencv_highgui, opencv_core, opencv_ml... to "Libraries"
6. Create a small project and compiled it.
7. The compiler complained about "opencv2/core/core_c.h：No such file or directory"...

I remember that when I install OpenCV on Ubuntu, I did compiled the project (it took quite a bit of time). Do I have to do the same thing on Windows? Or is any other thing causing this error?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054616/correct-includes-to-use-the-new-c-api-in-opencv-2-3

Comment: you got your include path wrong, see answer below. To answer question, OpenCV needs not to be compiled the .exe gives you precompiled binaries. But it's quite simple to compile using CMake

Answer (score 0):

You should add correct directories to includes.

Since you added `C:/opencv/include/opencv`, there is no way for compiler to find `C:/opencv/include/opencv2/core/core.h`.

I believe you should enter `C:/opencv/include/` to includes directories as well.